# Oracle Case Statement using OBIEE

Tags: sql, oracle, case, obiee

```
CASE WHEN ("Candidate Cycle Time"."Time From Req. First Approval To Offer Accept"-"Requisition Aging"."Time On Hold Since Creation") < 6 
THEN Null 
ELSE "Candidate Cycle Time"."Time From Req. First Approval To Offer Accept"-"Requisition Aging"."Time On Hold Since Creation"  
END
```

I have this case statement but need to add some info that is giving me a hard time.

So anything less than 6 should be null except for example values - 7654, 4567, 8013, 2038

How can I add this to my current case statement?

Comment: Are those seriously your table and column names...?

Comment: Case statements evaluate to the first true statment so put a statment in front of the one testing for less than siz that says IN (7654,4567...) THEN x value.  Also I agree with Siyual about table and column names that makes it very difficult to debug or even code!

Comment: Ya this information pulled out of Taleo using OBIEE so the column names are painful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CASE
    WHEN ("Candidate Cycle Time"."Time From Req. First Approval To Offer Accept"-"Requisition Aging"."Time On Hold Since Creation")
       IN (7654, 4567, 8013, 2038) THEN ???
    WHEN ("Candidate Cycle Time"."Time From Req. First Approval To Offer Accept"-"Requisition Aging"."Time On Hold Since Creation") < 6 
       THEN Null 
    ELSE "Candidate Cycle Time"."Time From Req. First Approval To Offer Accept"-"Requisition Aging"."Time On Hold Since Creation"  
END
```

Comment: CASE
    WHEN ("Candidate Cycle Time"."Time From Req. First Approval To Offer Accept"-"Requisition Aging"."Time On Hold Since Creation")
       IN (7071,) THEN "Candidate Cycle Time"."Time From Req. First Approval To Offer Accept"-"Requisition Aging"."Time On Hold Since Creation"
    WHEN ("Candidate Cycle Time"."Time From Req. First Approval To Offer Accept"-"Requisition Aging"."Time On Hold Since Creation") < 6 
       THEN Null 
    ELSE "Candidate Cycle Time"."Time From Req. First Approval To Offer Accept"-"Requisition Aging"."Time On Hold Since Creation"  
END

Comment: would that exclude the 7071 from the <6 rule?

Comment: yes, you do have an extra comma after 7071 that will cause a syntax error though.  To repeat a comment from above the 1st true statement is the one returned.  Which means that the <6 statement is never evaluated if the subtraction yields 7071

Comment: Thanks so much Matt!

Comment: your welcome if it works for you please accept the answer here is an article on how/when/why http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work